# unable to open gh pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have created my personal gh page at https://ninjaasmoke.github.io using `Create-react-app` 
I've used `gh-pages` from npm to host this on github pages. 
My username is `ninjaasmoke`. I also have other gh pages for other repos (like https://ninjaasmoke.github.io/angular/module-2-assignment/ ). But since I created my personal gh page, I’m unable to open the other repos’ pages! Everything I try, redirects me to my personal page. I thought it was because I was redirecting urls from my personal gh page, but that is not the case. Help!!!

Comment: can you give us another project in github that has gh-pages activated?

Comment: Hey I got help from GitHub community. It was because the service worker was registered in my personal gh page and all traffic was being redirected to it. I just had to unregister it and everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to unregister from the service worker in index.js (or index.ts) file. Apparently all the traffic was being redirected to the initial page because of this service worker. After unregistering, everything works fine